# Periodical binary representation

Tags: c++, algorithm, binary, period

How can I make a program that checks if binary representation of a given integer is periodical with period length m >= 2?

For example:

Binary representation of 10 is periodical

```
10 base 10 = 1010 base 2, periodical with period length 2
```

Binary representation of 9 is not periodical

```
9 base 10 = 1001 base 2
```

Binary representation of 153 is periodical

```
153 base 10 = 10011001 base 2, periodical with period length 4
```

Is there any specific algorithm for doing this?

I am working in C++.

Comment: I would say the same algorithm that for regex `(.+){2,}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is rotate the bits and check each time if the numbers are equal. i.e. the rotated one and the one you start with

```
// it is being assumed the size of int is 4bytes
int num = 153;
int temp = num;
int i = 0;
for (i=0; i<(8*sizeof(int))/2; i++){
    temp = ((temp >> 1) & LONG_MAX | temp << 31) // rotate the bits by 1
    if (!(temp ^ num)){ // check if the numbers are the same
        break;
    }
}
if (i<(8*sizeof(int))/2)
    std::cout << "Period is" << i << "\n";
else
    std::cout << "Not periodic";
```

The complexity is linear in the number of bits.

Answer (score 0):

KMP is the specific algorithm to find the period of any string, of source including the binary representation of a number, which is just a string. It run in O(n) time.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int calc_period(string s) {
  vector<int> pre(s.size());
  // this condition is keeped true in the for-loop:
  //    s[0..pre[i]] is this longest suffix of s[0..i] in s[0..i]'s all prefixes (if pre[i] >= 0)
  int k = -1;
  pre[0] = -1;
  for (int i = 1; i < int(s.size()); ++i) {
    while (k >= 0 && s[k + 1] != s[i]) {
      k = pre[k];
    }
    if (s[k + 1] == s[i]) {
      ++k;
    }
    pre[i] = k;
  }
  int l = s.size() - 1 - pre[s.size() - 1];
  return s.size() % l == 0 ? s.size() / l : 1;
}

string to_binary(long long x) {
  string s;
  if (x == 0) {
    s = "0";
  } else {
    while (x) {
      s += (x & 1) ? "1" : "0";
      x >>= 1;
    }
    reverse(s.begin(), s.end());
  }
  return s;
}

int main() {
  int x;
  cin >> x;
  cout << calc_period(to_binary(x)) << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

You can try this code out to see how it works. If you want to learn deeper about KMP, read its [wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm) or related text books such as "Introduction to Algorithm".